# Как получить значение из кнопки? Blazor

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, blazor

Всем привет. Столкнулся с немного глупой проблемой. У меня есть такой кусок кода со значениями кнопок и методом при нажатии, но как получить само значение кнопки для изменения экрана калькулятора?

```
<div class="text-center">
     <div class="calc">
        <div class="calc_screen">
            <p>@equation</p>
        </div>
        <div class="calc_buttons">
            <button class="calc_button ac bg-grey" value="AC" @onclick = "GetValue">AC</button>
            <button class="calc_button plus-minus bg-grey" value="+/-" @onclick = "GetValue">>+/-</button>
            <button class="calc_button percent bg-grey" value="%" @onclick = "GetValue">%</button>
            <button class="calc_button division bg-orange" value="/" @onclick = "GetValue">/</button>
            <button class="calc_button seven" value="7" @onclick = "GetValue">7</button>
            <button class="calc_button eight" value="8" @onclick = "GetValue">8</button>
            <button class="calc_button nine" value="9" @onclick = "GetValue">9</button>
            <button class="calc_button multiply bg-orange" value="X" @onclick = "GetValue">X</button>
            <button class="calc_button four" value="4" @onclick = "GetValue">4</button>
            <button class="calc_button five" value="5" @onclick = "GetValue">5</button>
            <button class="calc_button six" value="6" @onclick = "GetValue">6</button>
            <button class="calc_button minus bg-orange" value="-" @onclick = "GetValue">-</button>
            <button class="calc_button one" value="1" @onclick = "GetValue">1</button>
            <button class="calc_button two" value="2" @onclick = "GetValue">2</button>
            <button class="calc_button three" value="3" @onclick = "GetValue">3</button>
            <button class="calc_button plus bg-orange" value="+" @onclick = "GetValue">+</button>
            <button class="calc_button zero" value="0" @onclick = "GetValue">0</button>
            <button class="calc_button dot" value="," @onclick = "GetValue">,</button>
            <button class="calc_button equal bg-orange" value="=" @onclick = "GetValue">=</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
@code{
    private string equation = "0";
    private void GetValue(){
        equation =  "какое-то значение кнопки";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Самый простой да и нормальный способ- вызывать ф-цию с аргументом при клике:

```
<button class="calc_button ac bg-grey" value="AC" @onclick = "@(() =>GetValue("AC"))">AC</button>
<button class="calc_button plus-minus bg-grey" value="+/-" @onclick =  "@(() =>GetValue("+/-"))">>+/-</button>
<button class="calc_button percent bg-grey" value="%" @onclick = "@(() =>GetValue("%"))">%</button>

@code{
    private string equation = "0";
    private void GetValue(string value){
        Console.WriteLine(value);
    }
}
```

Фидл: https://blazorfiddle.com/s/tnloeb1w